# How to draw a Likert scale in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I tried to draw something like a Likert scale in SWT. The prototype looks like this:

[image]

This works more or less, but I would like to stretch the top row, where the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are printed to be stretched so that this group has the same size as the two radio button groups below. I just have no idea how to do that.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    Composite container = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, false);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    container.setLayout(layout);

    createRatingView(container);
    return area;
}

private void createRatingView(Composite container) {
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    Group r = new Group(container, SWT.END);
    r.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("1");
    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("2");
    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("3");
    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("4");
    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("5");
    new Label(r, SWT.NONE).setText("6");

    List<A> methods = B.getElements(currentObj);
    for (A method : methods) {
        Label element = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        element.setText(method.getMode().name());

        Label name = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        name.setText(method.getName());

        Group group = new Group(container, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
        group.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(1);
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(2);
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(3);
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(4);
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(5);
        new Button(group, SWT.RADIO).setData(6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a single 6 column GridLayout for the titles and buttons would get them lined up.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I arrange the buttons in a group then?